# No Stack Information - V(Unknown Source)

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my app, and wondering why I am not getting any stack information just;

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
            at com.x.y.z.()V(Unknown Source)
```

I am building using an Ant script - do I need to fiddle with some sort of compilation verbosity setting?

P.S. I am not interested in the NoClassDefFoundError, just the lack of stack trace.

Answer (score 6):

After some googling I found it.

Need to add the arguments;

```
debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source"
```

, to the javac task.